# Anyone have succeed to compile vslam package in electric?

Tags: ros, vslam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.
I'm trying to use vslam packge in electric, however, it shows an error about "pcl" and "opencv" all the time.
I even have installed all the dependencies that the vslam pkg needs.

Have anyone succeed to compile vslam pkg recently?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36910/anyone-have-succeed-to-compile-vslam-package-in-electric?/) by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 314 on 2012-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That part of the vslam wikipage where it says it's "experimental, unsupported, research code", and that it doesn't work anymore?

That's all true.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0